# ¿Como filtrar la información de un StreamReader?

Tags: c#, json, api, stream

Hola actualmente estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema usando una API de la pagina https://smn.cna.gob.mx/es/web-service-api, la cual funciona de la siguiente manera, al dar click se descarga un archivo .gz el cual se tiene que descomprimir y viene un archivo con toda la informacion del clima de todos los estados con todas las ciudades de México, el resultado lo arroja en JSON.

En mi programa ya puedo descargarlo en automatico y mostrarlo en consola pero ahora mi pregunta es ¿como puedo filtrar esta información de este JSON por el nombre de una ciudad y ademas poder guardar esta información en variables en mi programa?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetRequest("https://smn.cna.gob.mx/webservices/index.php?method=1");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    async static void GetRequest(String url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)) //obtener una variable con la info del url
        using (var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) //obtener la info del archivo
        using (var descomprimido = new GZipStream(content, CompressionMode.Decompress)) //descomprimir el archivo
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(descomprimido); 
                String data = reader.ReadLine(); // aqui data ya tiene toda la información del archivo, este es el que necesito filtrar
                Console.WriteLine(data); //Esto es solo para mostrarlo en consola
                StreamWriter escritura = File.CreateText("ejemplo122.txt");
                escritura.WriteLine(data); //Y aqui simplemente cree un archivo para visualizar mejor la información
                escritura.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Entonces ¿como podría filtrar yo esa información por ciudad y de que forma podría yo obtener la informacion para agregarlas a mis variables?
Este es un ejemplo de la información que me arroja

```
{"CityId":"MXAS0002",

"Name":"Aguascalientes",

"StateAbbr":"AGU",

"DayNumber":"0",

"ValidDateUtc":"20190318T000000Z",

"LocalValidDate":"20190318T070000Z",

"HiTempF":"77",

"LowTempF":"47",

"HiTempC":"25",

"LowTempC":"8",

"PhraseDay":"Nuboso. Máxima de 25 C. Vientos del OSO de 15 a 30 km/h.",

"PhraseNight":"Cielo mayormente despejado. Mínima de 8 C. Vientos del NNO de 15 a 25 km/h.",

"SkyText":"Nublado",

"ProbabilityOfPrecip":"0",

"RelativeHumidity":"22",

"WindSpeedMph":"15",

"WindSpeedKm":"24",

"WindDirection":"241",

"WindDirectionCardinal":"OSO",

"CloudCoverage":"77",

"UvIndex":"10",

"UvDescription":"Muy Alto",

"IconCode":"67",

"IconCodeNight":"97",

"SkyTextNight":"Despejado",

"Latitude":"21.87982",

"Longitude":"-102.296"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder manejar ese Json primero debes parsearlo o más bien convertirlo en un objeto que puedas manipular.

Para eso debes crear una clase con las propiedades similares a las que devuelve tu Json.

```
Public class InfoClima
{
   public string CityId { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public string StateAbbr { get; set;}
   public string DayNumber { get; set;}
   public string ValidDateUtc { get; set;}
   public string LocalValidDate { get; set;}
   public string HiTempF { get; set;}
   public string LowTempF { get; set;}
   public string HiTempC { get; set;}
   public string LowTempC { get; set;}
   public string PhraseDay { get; set;}
   public string PhraseNight { get; set;}
   public string SkyText { get; set;}
   public string ProbabilityOfPrecip { get; set;}
   public string RelativeHumidity { get; set;}
   public string WindSpeedMph { get; set;}
   public string WindSpeedKm { get; set;}
   public string WindDirection { get; set;}
   public string WindDirectionCardinal { get; set;}
   public string CloudCoverage { get; set;}
   public string UvIndex { get; set;}
   Public string UvDescription { get; set;}
   public string IconCode { get; set;}
   public string IconCodeNight { get; set;}
   public string SkyTextNight { get; set;}
   public string Latitude { get; set;}
   public string Longitude { get; set;}
}
```

Y en tu codigo convertir tu json a la clase (suponiendo que la api te devuelva varios objetos es decir un Json Array de lo contrario elimina la parte de `List<>`).

```
var listInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InfoClima>>(data);
```

Esto devuelve una lista de informaciones de clima y para obtener cada ciudad o información la iteramos con un ciclo.

```
foreach (var info in listInfo) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine( string.Format("id:{0}, nombre de ciudad:{1}", info.CityId, info.Name));
}
```

Se ha utilizado la libreria Newtonsoft puedes descargar desde los paquetes nugets.

*Nota:* En las propiedades de la clase he agregado los tipos de datos que muestras es decir `string` por lo que debes revisar eso en la documentación de la api o hacer varias pruebas.

Comment: Muchas gracias igualmente lo intentaré y espero y me salga

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias si funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes un `json` este se puede deserializar a una clase para tomar de esta los datos

Para esto necesitas de la libreria `json.net` la cual agregas usando nuget

[Newtonsoft.Json nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

teniendo el json puede crear una clase .net para deserializarla, la cual obtienes usando

http://json2csharp.com/

quedando algo como esto

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StateAbbr { get; set; }
    public string DayNumber { get; set; }
    public string ValidDateUtc { get; set; }
    public string LocalValidDate { get; set; }
    public string HiTempF { get; set; }
    public string LowTempF { get; set; }
    public string HiTempC { get; set; }
    public string LowTempC { get; set; }
    public string PhraseDay { get; set; }
    public string PhraseNight { get; set; }
    public string SkyText { get; set; }
    public string ProbabilityOfPrecip { get; set; }
    public string RelativeHumidity { get; set; }
    public string WindSpeedMph { get; set; }
    public string WindSpeedKm { get; set; }
    public string WindDirection { get; set; }
    public string WindDirectionCardinal { get; set; }
    public string CloudCoverage { get; set; }
    public string UvIndex { get; set; }
    public string UvDescription { get; set; }
    public string IconCode { get; set; }
    public string IconCodeNight { get; set; }
    public string SkyTextNight { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

para luego deserializar usando

[Cómo usar JSON en .NET fácilmente con C#](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Como-usar-JSON-en-NET-facilmente.aspx)

```
//resto codigo
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

al tener la clase puede acceder a las propiedades

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentaré y a ver que sale

Comment: Muchas gracias si funcionó